# Delphi/FPC Code no longer compiles under XCode after update to XE2 Update 2

Tags: ios, xcode, web-services, delphi, fpc

I have written an iOS app using Delphi XE2 (Firemonkey) to call a webservice.

The code has stopped compiling since I applied Delphi XE2 Update 2 - (Previously I was using update 1).
I have also updated the XCode to 4.2 and iOS5, however I *think* that have compiled okay since then (not 100% sure).  So I cannot confidently eliminate it as a suspect.

This is the code fragment that previously compiled ok (and worked nicely too!) under xcode using FPC.  I have applied the FPC and Firemonkey XE2 updates on the mac.

```
TSynWebServices_iOS = objcclass(NSURLConnection)
private
  reqURL:     NSURL;
  reqPacket:  NSMutableURLRequest;
  webData:    NSMutableData;
public
  function  init: id; override;
  procedure dealloc; override;
  //
  procedure connection_didReceiveResponse(connection: NSURLConnection;
                                          response: NSURLResponse); override;
  procedure connection_didReceiveData(connection: NSURLConnection; data: NSData); override;
  procedure connection_didFailWithError(connection: NSURLConnection; error: NSError); override;
  procedure connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection); override;
end;
```

Now I am getting the following errors...

```
SynWebServices_iOS_Unit.pas(44,15) Error: There is no method in an ancestor class to be overridden: "TSynWebServices_iOS.connection_didReceiveResponse(NSURLConnection,NSURLResponse);"
SynWebServices_iOS_Unit.pas(46,15) Error: There is no method in an ancestor class to be overridden: "TSynWebServices_iOS.connection_didReceiveData(NSURLConnection,NSData);"
SynWebServices_iOS_Unit.pas(47,15) Error: There is no method in an ancestor class to be overridden: "TSynWebServices_iOS.connection_didFailWithError(NSURLConnection,NSError);"
SynWebServices_iOS_Unit.pas(48,15) Error: There is no method in an ancestor class to be overridden: "TSynWebServices_iOS.connectionDidFinishLoading(NSURLConnection);"
SynWebServices_iOS_Unit.pas(44,15) Error: Objective-C messages require their Objective-C selector name to be specified using the "message" directive.
SynWebServices_iOS_Unit.pas(44,15) Error: Mismatch between number of declared parameters and number of colons in message string.
SynWebServices_iOS_Unit.pas(46,15) Error: Mismatch between number of declared parameters and number of colons in message string.
SynWebServices_iOS_Unit.pas(47,15) Error: Mismatch between number of declared parameters and number of colons in message string.
SynWebServices_iOS_Unit.pas(48,15) Error: Mismatch between number of declared parameters and number of colons in message string.
SynWebServices_iOS_Unit.pas(56,1) Fatal: There were 9 errors compiling module, stopping
Fatal: Compilation aborted
```

Looking at what appears to be the include file for FPC - 'NSURLConnection.inc' -
these methods are not defined for NSURLConnection, however they are defined for the class NSURLConnectionDelegateCategory.

If I try to inherit from NSURLConnectionDelegateCategory instead however, the class is not recognised.

Has anyone else encountered this issue, or managed to use NSURLConnection under XE2 update 2?

Thanks

Comment: Did you make a diff between the two source trees?

Comment: My source hasn't changed. Only thing which has changed is the compiler version and whatever was shipped with it. This is not under source control.